# DynamoDb querying Enum

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to dynamoDB and this question might be juvenile.

I am trying to query an item from the table but dynamo api is not able to convert the query json result into the class instance because there is an enum variable member present in the class.

> My class Structure:[note that RequestStage is a Enum member]

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "LoadInfoProvider")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class LoadInfoProvider {

/** The load request ID. */
@DynamoDBRangeKey
private String loadRequestID;

/** The load request creation id. */
@DynamoDBHashKey
private String loadRequestCreationId;

/** The carrier ID. */
private String carrierID;

/** The carrier pool. */
private String carrierPool;

/** The carrier details. */
private CarrierDetail carrierDetails;

/** The driver assignment required. */
private Boolean driverAssignmentRequired;

/** The driver pool. */
private String driverPool;

/** The trailer attachment required. */
private Boolean trailerAttachmentRequired;

/** The request type. */
private String requestType;

/** The request stage. */
private RequestStage requestStage;

/** The created time. */
private String createdTime;

/** The consumed time. */
private String consumedTime;

/** The provider status. */
private String providerStatus;

/** The is consumed. */
private Boolean isConsumed;

/** The request status. */
private RequestStatus requestStatus;

/** The trip. */
private Trip trip;
}
```

> RequestStageEnum :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@DynamoDBDocument
public enum RequestStage {

/** The initiated. */
INITIATED("initiated"),

/** The passed. */
PASSED("passed"),

/** The failed. */
FAILED("failed");

/** The value. */
@Getter
@Setter
private String value;

}
```

When i query something from this table, i am getting the below error.

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Failed to instantiate new instance of class
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.createObject(ConversionSchemas.java:614)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.unconvert(ConversionSchemas.java:414)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.unmarshallers.ObjectUnmarshaller.unmarshall(ObjectUnmarshaller.java:54)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.unmarshallers.NullableUnmarshaller.unmarshall(NullableUnmarshaller.java:46)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.unmarshall(ConversionSchemas.java:593)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.unconvert(ConversionSchemas.java:426)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.privateMarshallIntoObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:630)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObjects(DynamoDBMapper.java:661)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedQueryList.(PaginatedQueryList.java:65)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.query(DynamoDBMapper.java:1856)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.query(DynamoDBMapper.java:1844)
>       at com.amazon.optimus.dynamoHelper.DynamoDBUtil.queryRecord(DynamoDBUtil.java:112)
>       at com.amazon.optimus.dynamoHelper.DynamoDBUtil.main(DynamoDBUtil.java:164)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.amazon.optimus.enums.RequestStage
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.createObject(ConversionSchemas.java:611)
>       ... 12 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.amazon.optimus.enums.RequestStage.()
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
>       ... 13 more

It's clear from the exception, java is not able to instantiate the enum. How i can fix this and make this working? Your help is appreciated and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate your field `requestStage` with `@DynamoDBMarshalling`.

Assuming `RequestStage` is an `enum`, here's what your marshaller might look like:

```
    public class RequestStageMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<RequestStage> {

        @Override
        public String marshall(RequestStage requestStage) {
            return requestStage.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public RequestStage unmarshall(Class<RequestStage> clazz, String 
requestStage) {
            return RequestStage.valueOf(requestStage);
        }

    }
```

Then you'd annotate your `requestStage` field like so:

```
@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = RequestStageMarshaller.class)
private RequestStage requestStage
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out this. I am accepting this as answer since you spend your time helping me and the better solution is to use annotation [at]DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum and avoid marshalling.

Comment: @santhoshkumar the latest DynamoDB API has `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum` that obviates the need for a special marshaller: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum.html